# NSIS - Installer: Compare Kit Version with Header file define variable and update if wrong define variable value

Tags: scripting, nsis

I'm new to NSIS installer scripting. I have created a NSIS script to replace our WISE installer script. I want to write a logic to compare Kit version(Folder name say A1.2.3 where A denotes Alhpa kit) with !define APP_Version(on header) file during compile time and if define variable is wrong, I want to update Header file with correct value. Here is the logic I came up with but I don't know how to update the update the header file.

Section

```
System::Call "kernel32::GetCurrentDirectory(i ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}, t .r0)"

${WordFind} "$0" "\" "-1" $R0

!if "$R0" != "${APP_CLASSKIT}${APP_VERSION}"
    MessageBox MB_OK "No Match: $R0"
    !undef verifykit
    !define APP_VERSION "$R0"
    
!else
    MessageBox MB_OK "Match: ${APP_CLASSKIT}${APP_VERSION}"
    !undef verifykit
    !define APP_VERSION "${APP_CLASSKIT}${APP_VERSION}"
!endif
```

SectionEnd

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix and match run-time and compile-time instructions like that. If you want to detect this on the machine you are compiling on you can only use the instructions starting with `!`.

If you just want to detect the problem:

```
!macro PrepareExample
!system 'mkdir ".\A1.2.3"'
!macroend
!insertmacro PrepareExample ; For Stackoverflow


!define APP_CLASSKIT A 
!define APP_VERSION 1.2.3

!if ! /FileExists ".\${APP_CLASSKIT}${APP_VERSION}\*"
!error "Incorrect kit version, ${APP_CLASSKIT}${APP_VERSION} not found!"
!endif

Section
SetOutPath $InstDir
File /r ".\${APP_CLASSKIT}${APP_VERSION}"
SectionEnd
```

The compile-time part of the compiler is not really suited to search for folders with a specific pattern. It is much better to invoke a batch/powershell/wsh script and let that create a .nsh file you can include:

```
!macro PrepareExample
!system 'mkdir ".\A1.2.3"'
!delfile 'findkit.bat'
!appendfile 'findkit.bat' '@echo off$\r$\n'
!appendfile 'findkit.bat' 'echo.TODO: Use FOR or some other batch command to find the correct kit folder.$\r$\n'
!appendfile 'findkit.bat' 'for /D %%A in (??.*) do ($\r$\n'
!appendfile 'findkit.bat' ' echo.This batch file just fakes it$\r$\n'
!appendfile 'findkit.bat' ' echo !define APP_CLASSKIT A >> "%~1"$\r$\n'
!appendfile 'findkit.bat' ' echo !define APP_VERSION 1.2.3 >> "%~1"$\r$\n'
!appendfile 'findkit.bat' ')$\r$\n'
!macroend
!insertmacro PrepareExample ; For Stackoverflow


!tempfile KitNsh
!system '"findkit.bat" "${KitNsh}"'
!include "${KitNsh}"
!delfile "${KitNsh}"
!ifndef APP_CLASSKIT | APP_VERSION
  !error "No kit detected"
!endif
!echo "Using kit ${APP_CLASSKIT}${APP_VERSION}"

Section
...
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Anders. As per your suggestion, I have created a script to create a batch file and when executed, that will create a compiler.nsh(header file) for Build.nsi(Main script). However, I'm confused how I can integrate this into my current main script. |

I want my Build.nsi to run the script to create and execute the batch file first, it then creates compiler.nsh file which will be in the Build.nsi to access the defined variables for building a kit.

Comment: Use !system in your .nsi to run the batch like I do in the 2nd example.

Comment: I'm trying to resolve variables inside my !appendfile statement like, 

!appendfile 'findkit.bat' ' echo !define CLASSKIT ${APP_CLASSKIT}  >> "%~1"$\r$\n'

but the ${APP_CLASSKIT} is not getting resolved. am I missing something? or do I need to add any escaping command to resolve this variable?

Comment: Maybe it is not defined at that point. Anyway, you don't have to use !appendfile, you can just write a normal bat file in your text editor.